# Subclassing a UITableViewController without nib or storyboard?

Tags: ios, uikit, uitableview, subclass

I'm trying to subclass UITableViewController just with just code without a nib or storyboard. Upon loading its view I get this error:

```
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "BYZ-38-tfr-view-1bC-Xs-vdC" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
```

I've tried setting `self.tableView` with a new table view in `:loadView` but that doesn't fix it, nor does setting it in any initializers. Any solutions?

**Edit**: The class is a plain subclass of UITableViewController generated from the "new file" menu. No customizations have been made.

It may help to note that the project itself has a storyboard, and I'm loading the UITableViewController subclass by making the app's starting view controller to be the subclass.

The error is easily reproducible by creating a new single-view template project in Xcode, generating a plain UITableViewController subclass, and setting the only view controller in the storyboard to be of the UITableViewController subclass type.

**Edit 2**: Problem solved, check comments.

Comment: Seems like it's still trying to load from a nib. Show us how you subclassed it maybe?

Comment: Did you override `loadView`? could you show `loadView` code?

Comment: Yes, I overrided `loadView`. I literally just added `self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc]init];` and then `[super loadView]`. As for the subclass, I haven't customized it in any way. I had just created it from the new file menu as a subclass of UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by avoiding any storyboard whatsoever. Originally I had it being loaded via the projects main storyboard. Instead, I now load up the subclass instance in a separate view controller, avoiding the error.